# got error "incompatible types: void cannot be converted to int" in OOP

Tags: java, oop

I'm pretty new to Java and stackoverflow so sorry for any confusions. Below is my code and I got the following errors:

```
./LETest.java:8: error: incompatible types: void cannot be converted to int
int returned = savingsTest.withdraw(200);
^
./LETest.java:18: error: incompatible types: void cannot be converted to int
int returned = savingsTest.withdraw(500);
^
2 errors
```

The IDE did print out the following results though:

```
Hello!
Your balance is
You just deposited 500
You just withdrew 200
```

Code:

```
public class SavingsAccount {
  
  int balance;
  int amountToDeposit;
  int amountToWithdraw;
  
  // initial balance
  public SavingsAccount(int initialBalance){
    balance = initialBalance;
  }

  // check balance
  public void checkBalance(){
    System.out.println("Hello!");
    System.out.println("Your balance is " + balance);
  }
  
  // deposit
  public void deposit(int amountToDeposit){
    balance = balance + amountToDeposit;
    System.out.println("You just deposited " + amountToDeposit);
  }

  // withdraw
  public void withdraw(int amountToWithdraw){
    balance = balance - amountToWithdraw;
    System.out.println("You just withdrew " + amountToWithdraw);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
    SavingsAccount savings = new SavingsAccount(2000);

    savings.checkBalance();
    savings.deposit(500);
    savings.withdraw(200);

  }       
}
```

Would someone mind helping?

I tried changing void to int in the withdraw() method and got a new error

```
SavingsAccount.java:30: error: missing return statement
  }
  ^
1 error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know you want to change the return type of `withdraw` to `int`. And you know you were missing a `return`. Presumably you want to return the *`newBalance`*. So add that. Like,

```
// Withdraw. Take an int. Return an int.
public int withdraw(int amountToWithdraw) {
    int newBalance = balance - amountToWithdraw;
    balance = newBalance;
    System.out.println("You just withdrew " + amountToWithdraw);
    return newBalance; // The int to return.
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Another question: why am I supposed to use int instead of void? No errors occurred during the deposit method.

Comment: `int returned = savingsTest.withdraw(200);` requires that `savingsTest.withdraw` return an `int`. Otherwise it makes no sense. What `int` should be assigned to `returned` when the method returns nothing? Try `int returned = savings.deposit(500);` for the **exact** same error.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is slightly different than what is reported in the error.

```
./LETest.java:8: error: incompatible types: void cannot be converted to int
int returned = savingsTest.withdraw(200);
^
./LETest.java:18: error: incompatible types: void cannot be converted to int
int returned = savingsTest.withdraw(500);
^
2 errors
```

These errors are reporting from lines *8* and *18*.

```java
int returned = savingsTest.withdraw(200);
int returned = savingsTest.withdraw(500);
```

Which, is not in the code you provided.

Nevertheless, I'll explain the situation you encountered.

In Java, a method is declared with a return type.
If you don't intend on returning a value, you can use *void*.
*[Defining Methods (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language > Classes and Objects)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)*.

The error you're encountering is because you're attempting to assign a *void* to an *int*.
The *withdraw* method is declared as void.

You mention the following.

> *"I tried changing void to int in the withdraw() method and got a new error"*

The error encountered here is because, if a method is declared with a return type, you must use the *return* keyword, and the value.
*[Returning a Value from a Method (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language > Classes and Objects)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html)*.

For example, if you wanted to return a value from the *withdraw* method, you could use the following.

```java
public int withdraw(int amountToWithdraw){
    balance = balance - amountToWithdraw;
    System.out.println("You just withdrew " + amountToWithdraw);
    return balance;
}
```

Additionally, the correct accounting term would be, *withdrawal*.